# Control TimerTask on java server

Tags: java, servlets, controls, timertask

I have ~10 TimerTask executed on Weblogic server.

What is a best way to control execution of these task (stop , run , state) from e.g. servlet in the same application.

I need solution for java version 1.4. I know how to make simple manager with JNDI + TimerTask but i want any standart solution, not reenvent wheel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at the [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) scheduler.  Either to use it to replace your TimerTasks with Jobs or to get ideas.  Not sure if the latest versions run on Java 1.4 but some of the older ones should.

Comment: I found temporary solution as CommonJ.